# How to switch between python and java using eclipse

Tags: java, python, eclipse

I have just installed pydev on eclipse to write a simple python project. Now I would like to switch back to using java in eclipse. In my project explorer window I do not see any of my java projects. When I go to file-> import -> Existing Projects into Workspace, all of the java projects are greyed out (not selectable). Do you know how I can switch between python and java using eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to java environment in eclipse then only you would be able to import java project !

refer this :
http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-9f.htm